# hbase table describe <tablename> in a more readable format like RDBMS

Tags: hadoop, hbase

how to  display "describe tablename" in hbase in a more readable format like RDBMS. Can we display the column names in describe tablename

describe gives me something like ,which is not what the normal desired user friendly ,easily understandable as in rdbms

## can we make it readable like RDBMS ,clearly indicating about the column families, column names and their data types in a more concrete form(in a Table Type) especially about the columns inside the CF .

```
describe 'emp', {NAME ⇒ 'READONLY', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING ⇒ 'NONE',     BLOOMFILTER
⇒ 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE ⇒ '0', COMPRESSION ⇒ 'NONE', VERSIONS ⇒
'1', TTL true
```

Comment: You can use the list, and describe commands for getting the list of tables, and inspect the table’s for getting list of column families respectively. HBase does not have explicit column declarations and types, so you cannot get this information because it is not stored or enforced. You can check http://hbase.apache.org/book/datamodel.html for more info.

Comment: can we code to make the display of the describe tablename more cleaner and easier to read

Comment: you can. But, whats not clean in that?

Comment: If you want like RDBMS, then you should proably use Apache Phoenix on top of HBase: http://phoenix.apache.org/

Comment: i have edited my question above ,tks for ur suggestion, I would like to understand how I can code in java to make the describe in a more presentable way and easier to understand

Comment: can we make it readable like RDBMS ,clearly indicating about the column families, column names and their data types  in a more concrete form(in a Table Type) especially about the columns inside the CF .Is is feature available in phoenix?